# laravel route::resource can't find edit function in my controller

Tags: php, laravel, routes

When I call my edit function I get a 404|not found page.

this is the code in my View

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.edit', $user->id) }}">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm crudbtn">Edit</button>
</a>
```

This is the code in my web.php

```
 route::namespace('Admin')->prefix('admin')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin'])->name('admin.')->group(function(){
    route::resource('/', 'AdminController');
});
```

This is my edit function in my AdminController

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if(Auth::user()->id == $id){
        return redirect()->route('admin.index');
    }

    return view('admin.edit')->with(['user' => user::find($id), 'roles' => Role::all()]);
}
```

And this is the output of my php artisan route:list

```
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                    | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware          |
+--------+-----------+------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                      |                  | Closure                                                                | web                 |
|        | POST      | admin                  | admin.store      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@store                       | web,auth,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin                  | admin.index      | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@index                       | web,auth,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/create           | admin.create     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@create                      | web,auth,auth.admin |
|        | DELETE    | admin/{}               | admin.destroy    | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@destroy                     | web,auth,auth.admin |
|        | PUT|PATCH | admin/{}               | admin.update     | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@update                      | web,auth,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{}               | admin.show       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@show                        | web,auth,auth.admin |
|        | GET|HEAD  | admin/{}/edit          | admin.edit       | App\Http\Controllers\Admin\AdminController@edit                        | web,auth,auth.admin |
```

When i call my index function the proper page is loaded, but I can't figure out why my edit function cant' be found. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Did you get an error or you just been redirected to admin.index ?

Comment: i get  redirected to the 404 | not found page but my url is http://localhost/admin/2/edit

Comment: The parameter name is empty: `{}`. Route should be something like `route::resource('admins', 'AdminController');` https://laravel.com/docs/master/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
route::namespace('Admin')->middleware(['auth', 'auth.admin'])->group(function(){
    route::resource('admin', 'AdminController');
});
```

Comment: That changes my URI from admin/{}/edit to admin/admin/{admin}/edit
And the Name from admin.edit to admin.admin.edit

Comment: @Jiren make sure you remove `->prefix('admin')` and `->name('admin.')`